# C/C++/Data Structure online test

Tags: c++, c

I have to prepare for an entrance exam of C DAC(Centre for Development of Advanced Computing).
So please would somebody tell me Websites where I can practice for C,C++ and data structures quiz of Intermediate and expert level.(Objective type)
(Of course I'd like to check my accuracy and programming skills).
any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For C++, see this list:

[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

When I was at high-school I used to train myself for Computing Olympiads using [USACO Training Program](http://train.usaco.org/usacogate).